# Inputting SMP unicode characters

Tags: windows-xp, text-editors, unicode

I'm looking for a way to actually use Plane 1 - Supplementary Multilingual Plane - characters (i.e. `U+10000` to `U+1FFFD`) without having to manually encode the bytes with a hex editor.

Is there an alternative to the built-in Character Map application that would let me get at them and transfer them to general text editors?
I already have fonts installed that provide the glyphs I want.

Comment: http://babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html

Answer (score 2):

The [UnicodeInput](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/unicodeinput/) program can be used, but only when the second digit in a 5-digit number is not a letter. So you can enter U+10000 but not U+1D400. I think I reported the problem to the author of the program, but it’s an old program and might be difficult to fix.

Long ago (in 2000, really) I wrote a simple JavaScript-based CharMap-like utility, working on a web browser, for Unicode input: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/gwrite/ It covers just BMP, but I suppose it could be modified to deal with SMP, too. It should really be rewritten rather than extended, but the point is that something like this would be relatively simple to implement.

Answer (score -1):

Find a CharacterMap application under `Start/Programs/Accessories/System Tools` menu. This app allows you to browse all fonts and scripts and click & copy the text using these characters

Comment: It only goes up to U+FFFD

Comment: @OrangeDog Sorry, I had no chance to verify)